# Form placeholder/watermark and saved passwords

Tags: jquery, forms, authentication, watermark, placeholder

I am currently writing a login form on a website. It is required that the form is compact, and that the labels should be placed as placeholders/watermarks inside the email and password fields.

HTML5 introduces the placeholder attribute, but it is not very well supported. Therefore I have looked into a number of jQuery plugins that adds placeholder functionality to browsers that does not natively support it.

But... none of them really work with browser saved passwords.

The problem typically occurs when a user have saved two or more logins/passwords. Then, when selecting one of their logins, one of following happens:

1) The password is inserted behind the placeholder, and the placeholder is still shown. THe user may then think their password is not entered.

2) The password is inserted behind the placeholder, and it now shows the password dots and a placeholder on top of each other. Confusing and ugly.

3) The password is inserted as clear text in the placeholder, and is editable as clear text (yargh!)

As far as I can see, the cause of the problem is that no event is triggered when the browser inserts saved logins.

Does anyone know of some nifty Javascript that does not break when a user has saved more than one login?

Or can it really be true that noone has solved this problem? (highly unlikely)

Thanks.

Comment: The browser inserting a saved input field doesn't trigger a "change" event on that input field?

Comment: @Ben, it depends on the browser.  In jQuery `$('input, select, textarea').change()` should trigger it.

Comment: @scott, I understand how to catch the change event in jQuery, but @Anders said that "As far as I can see, the cause of the problem is that no event is triggered when the browser inserts saved logins.". I just wanted to confirm that he checked for the "change" event here.

Comment: @Ben, I wasn't trying to be argumentative, just that some browsers don't trigger the change event.  The jQuery was more for @Anders benefit.

Comment: Ah, got it. Misread your comment at first, sorry.

Comment: I have not fully tested the event issue in all browsers and with all the plugins I have tried, and I don't feel competent enough to modify them to fix the problems. Probably shouldn't have mentioned it :)

Also, many of the plugins even fail with one saved password:

With https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder, the password field simply dissappers in IE8.

http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder breaks by not showing that a password is inserted.

I'm quite surprised that such a simple feature has no solution.

Comment: I’m the author of the latter plugin mentioned by @Anders. As far as I know, this is a browser issue and sadly, there doesn’t seem to be a way around it.

Comment: @Mathias: Yeah, that's my conclusion too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a solution for a problem, but maybe you can avoid it with a little trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/tf3sC/

Place the labels behind the inputs and show / hide them.